# A research facility, spanning hundreds of kilometers, in a Pentagon-sized building: How can it construct its rooms?

Tags: science-based, construction

After I reached the net worth of Steve Jobs in collateral damage, during my most recent battle, the rest of the world decided to suppress me for obvious reasons. My only request was a small land, the size of the Pentagon, where I'd spend the rest of eternity slurping tea with Glarnak. Yeah, I was lying.

**My brilliant masterplan is to create an enormous facility, where each room exists as long as I'm present in it, and is created seconds before I enter like an old video game.**

Here's the basic floorplan for the facility:
[image]

### The IRL Loading screen

These are the "real rooms", the one marked with the heart is where you can enter the facility. Each room has a maximum number of doors, there can be less than that though.

Traversing the facility works by going to a door and pressing a button. The door will take time opening, as the construction of the new room only began when the button was pushed. Once the door opened, the new location can be entered. If you wish to proceed further into the facility, you will have to push a different button in one of the two rooms, doing so will close all doors in the room you're in, deconstruct the other and begin constructing another. Kinda like how a game loads zones.

Certain items can be "teleported" between rooms, basically just a conveyor belt beneath the floor that blinds you by igniting magnesium dust while taking the item in. It doesn't involve time-space bending shenanigans, but it looks neat.

There are several hurdles in my way, the first is creating the rooms.

- The process has to be relatively energy-efficient
- Material costs should be low too
- Speed would be important, as I can't keep the doors budging forever while the environment is being created.
- The rooms are usually created from geometric shapes, with some edges rounded, nothing particularly elaborate.
- The environment's only function is to be there and look pretty, being fire-resistant and chemically inert would be great too.
- Various functional tools and equipment will be covered in another episode.
- The most important thing about the rooms is that they contain information, in the form of sticky notes, books, and papers.

**Keeping these in mind, what would be the best way to create these rooms?**

Comment: Frame Challenge: "You want how much land!? Ha! Right. We'll give you a 6x8 concrete room. All we can spare at the moment."

Comment: cant you just make the building look like its within the property restraints and you really just build it underground, with this method you could build it a thousand times larger and without all the expensive machinary.

Comment: Do you have acceass to Gallifrey Technology?

Comment: @EliasRowanAlbatross Yeah, but where's the fun (or challenge) in that? Running circles in a Pentagon-sized holodeck is funnier.

Comment: @MichaelKutz No, I don't have plot armor.

Comment: @Mephistopheles indeed, it is an easy solution. sorry it wasn't what you were looking for. Good luck :)

Comment: @EliasRowanAlbatross To be frank, there'd have been a 50/50 chance that they'll discover it and nuke the whole place

Comment: Is it correct that you are talking about real-material recreation of a room  in a split seconds and teleportation? Not virtual reality or anything like that? Because if that's correct, I don't see how we can apply "science-based" tag here.

Comment: @Frostfyre Don't bring up concerns that can be addressed in one word: Siberia

Comment: If the world's countries are banding together to suppress you, why would they give you any land area when they can just put you in a maximum security cell where you can't pose a threat? If someone started a war with me, lost, then asked me to give him an army as his punishment, you can bet I'm going to refuse.

Comment: @Frostfyre It's not relevant to the question,  but if you asked, this character can only be "controlled" through contracts. If you simply just put him in a one-man labor camp at Recsk, you can bet he'll just hotswap into president covfefe and leak all the confidental information on twitter.

Comment: the biggest hurdle isn't magic, seems to be time & noise. The simple answer, it seems to me, is to have a 'radar' system which tracks the position of all items within a room, all structures(walls, furniture) are constructed of a fractal(?) material that can be 'cut to size' without actually 'breaking' the material(interlocking magnetic plates(?), finish can be variable with https://patents.google.com/patent/US8017217B1/en & other methods without needing to resort to huge stockpiles of materials.

Comment: The room can either be built in-situ with robotics or built(maintained) underground in a larger space and raised into place on an elevator. If you're reusing the same rooms and/or furniture, it's in concept a trivial matter to have a database with the designs of a range of objects, remove the required number of plates from a pile and have a robotic manipulator use any one of a number of methods to coordinate the 'tiles' altho the tiles could be self assembling by such a method as electromagnetic polarization  and locking thru internal circuitry.